# Why is there a padding in IP packet?

Tags: ip, padding, packet

I make some recap but I can't figure out what the padding is for in the IP packet?

[image]

figure taken from [here](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section3/7.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'options' field is variable length, and the padding field is used to bring packet header length to a multiple of 32 bits

Comment: It is to bring the packet *header* to a multiple of 32 bits.

Answer (score 6):

Padding is basically used to make sure that the IP packet header has a length that is a multiple of 32 bits. It is needed because of the varying length of the options field in the IP header.

Answer (score 3):

From that page:

> The internet header padding is used to ensure that the internet header ends on a 32 bit boundary. The padding is zero.

Comment: Probably so that 32-bit systems don't perform unaligned reads on the payload.

Answer (score 3):

If one or more options are included, and the number of bits used for them is not a multiple of 32, enough zero bits are added to “pad out” the header to a multiple of 32 bits (4 bytes).